# Running Skaffold fails if configured to work with Helm

Tags: kubernetes, deployment, kubernetes-helm, skaffold, google-cloud-code

I am trying to make Skaffold work with Helm.

Below is my ***skaffold.yml*** file:

```
apiVersion: skaffold/v2beta23
kind: Config
metadata:
  name: test-app
build:
  artifacts:
  - image: test.common.repositories.cloud.int/manager/k8s
    docker:
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
deploy:
  helm:
    releases:
    - name: my-release
      artifactOverrides:
        image: test.common.repositories.cloud.int/manager/k8s
      imageStrategy:
        helm: {}
```

Here is my ***values.yaml***:

```
image:
  repository: test.common.repositories.cloud.int/manager/k8s
  tag: 1.0.0
```

Running the *skaffold* command results in:

```
...
Starting deploy...
Helm release my-release not installed. Installing...
Error: INSTALLATION FAILED: failed to download ""
deploying "my-release": install: exit status 1
```

Does anyone have an idea, what is missing here?!

Comment: I believe your chart name is missing. Check your helm config.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this is happening because you have not specified a chart to use for the helm release. I was able to reproduce your issue by commenting out the `chartPath` field in the `skaffold.yaml` file of the [`helm-deployment` example](https://github.com/GoogleContainerTools/skaffold/tree/main/examples/helm-deployment) in the Skaffold repo.

You can specify a local chart using the [`deploy.helm.release.chartPath`](https://skaffold.dev/docs/references/yaml/#deploy-helm-releases-chartPath) field or a remote chart using the [`deploy.helm.release.remoteChart`](https://skaffold.dev/docs/references/yaml/#deploy-helm-releases-remoteChart) field.

Comment: Adding deploy.helm.release.chartPath solved the problem! Many thanks!